# How do I configure routing with two optional route values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is my route config in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{tab?}");
});
```

Some of my views make use of both `id` and `tab`, some just `id` and some just `tab`.

`id` is of type `Guid`, and `tab` is of type `int`.

How can I configure my routing to eliminate the `id`-part (`/0`) in the following url to a view which does not make use of it?

```
/Home/Index/0/3 // id is not relevant, tab = 3
```

In this case, I have to set `id` to `0` in order for the url to work. This is an index-view with sub sections organized in tabs.

Comment: Is there any order for the url parameter or any specific data type or other thing ? For example if you pass /Home/Index/1  ( 1 may be Id or 1 may be tab). Is there difference over here.

Comment: @dotnetstep `id`s are `Guid` and `tab`s are `int`. The `id` will always be before `tab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can do something like. As per your comment Id is guid and tab is int.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "onlyid",
                  pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id:guid}", new { tab = default(int) });

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "onlytab",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{tab:int}", new { id = default(Guid) } );

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id:Guid}/{tab:int}");
            });
```

Now if there is only tab then onlyTab will get choose and it has default value for Guid ( Guid.Empty) but you can address like /Home/Index/1 .

If there is only id then onlyId will get selected and it has default value for integer.  Home/Index/yourguid

If you pass both then third route get selected.

Method as Controller look like following.

```
 public IActionResult Index(Guid? id,int? tab)
        {
            return Ok(new { Id = id, Tab = tab });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{tab}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, tab= UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

[image]

[image]
this like we can pass variable type and reference type parameter

Comment: Post code as text between code tags instead of images, makes it easier to work with.

Comment: Will this method make it possible to have JUST `id` or JUST `tab`?

Comment: I don't think your solution is suitable for my .net version. I don't have a method in my `Startup.cs` called `RegisterRoutes()`, and if I try to place `routes.MapRoute(...)` inside the `Configure()`-method that I DO have, `routes.` is not recognized. If I change it to `app.MapRoute(...)`, the parameter `UrlParameter` is not recognized.

Comment: Could you please install package "System.Web.Mvc"

Comment: Cannot find any nuget package with that name. Closest I could find was `System.Web.Mvc.Extensions` by someone called hzbc. Looked suspicious, I thought...

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) and
install this package - Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Comment: I would like to keep to asp.net core (.net 5), and not install packages for older versions of .net.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
[Route("Home/{tab?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string tab)
{
    // do stuff
}
```